# Not able to send email notification in jenkins from outlook

Tags: jenkins, email-notifications

I want to Send email in Jenkins from outlook and I have given all the setting to jenkins like smtp of outlook, smtp port number etc but still i can't send email but with gmail account I'm able to send email from jenkins.

[Here is the Image of setting I used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYWaS.png)

Note: I run Jenkins Using Command java -jar jenkins.war

Here is the Error i get
[Error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgcyu.png)

[Error with TLS setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwPzb.png)

Comment: Please provide the error message. Check the build log.

Comment: I have attached the error.

Answer (score 0):

Activate TLS as it is described on the [microsoft website](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/pop-imap-and-smtp-settings-for-outlook-com-d088b986-291d-42b8-9564-9c414e2aa040?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

> SMTP server name smtp.office365.com
>
> SMTP port 587
>
> SMTP encryption method STARTTLS

To activate STARTTLS start jenkins like this:

```
java -Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true -jar jenkins.war
```

Comment: yes, i have tried TLS also but I am also having error with that. I have added the snap of error in my question.

Comment: Thanks. I amended my answer. Please give it a another shot.

Comment: still not able to send email with your mentioned command to run jenkins